# Override Localization of Identity in.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to override the localization of scaffold Identity in .NET Core 2.2. I simple created an override file inhereting `IdentityErrorDescriber` and injected in `Startup.cs` as my code shows above. Some how i can't get it work. Any clue?

**Startup.cs**

```
[...]
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
         .AddErrorDescriber<LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
[...]
```

**LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber.cs**

```
public class LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
   public override IdentityError DefaultError() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DefaultError), Description = $"Um erro desconhecido ocorreu." }; }
   public override IdentityError ConcurrencyFailure() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(ConcurrencyFailure), Description = "Falha de concorrência otimista, o objeto foi modificado." }; }
   public override IdentityError PasswordMismatch() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordMismatch), Description = "Senha incorreta." }; }
   public override IdentityError InvalidToken() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(InvalidToken), Description = "Token inválido." }; }
   public override IdentityError LoginAlreadyAssociated() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(LoginAlreadyAssociated), Description = "Já existe um usuário com este login." }; }
   public override IdentityError InvalidUserName(string userName) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(InvalidUserName), Description = $"Login '{userName}' é inválido, pode conter apenas letras ou dígitos." }; }
   public override IdentityError InvalidEmail(string email) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(InvalidEmail), Description = $"Email '{email}' é inválido." }; }
   public override IdentityError DuplicateUserName(string userName) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DuplicateUserName), Description = $"Login '{userName}' já está sendo utilizado." }; }
   public override IdentityError DuplicateEmail(string email) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DuplicateEmail), Description = $"Email '{email}' já está sendo utilizado." }; }
   public override IdentityError InvalidRoleName(string role) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(InvalidRoleName), Description = $"A permissão '{role}' é inválida." }; }
   public override IdentityError DuplicateRoleName(string role) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DuplicateRoleName), Description = $"A permissão '{role}' já está sendo utilizada." }; }
   public override IdentityError UserAlreadyHasPassword() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(UserAlreadyHasPassword), Description = "Usuário já possui uma senha definida." }; }
   public override IdentityError UserLockoutNotEnabled() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(UserLockoutNotEnabled), Description = "Lockout não está habilitado para este usuário." }; }
   public override IdentityError UserAlreadyInRole(string role) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(UserAlreadyInRole), Description = $"Usuário já possui a permissão '{role}'." }; }
   public override IdentityError UserNotInRole(string role) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(UserNotInRole), Description = $"Usuário não tem a permissão '{role}'." }; }
   public override IdentityError PasswordTooShort(int length) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordTooShort), Description = $"Senhas devem conter ao menos {length} caracteres." }; }
   public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric), Description = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um caracter não alfanumérico." }; }
   public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresDigit() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresDigit), Description = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um digito ('0'-'9')." }; }
   public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresLower() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresLower), Description = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um caracter em caixa baixa ('a'-'z')." }; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with current code. What do you mean it did not work?

Comment: Unfortunately only on my localhost. Well i meant that the `override` is not called at all. The IdentityError shows only in english. Where you successful with the override? Did you get the `Description` defined in the `LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber`class?

Comment: I got expected error when I register new user if I enter invalid password. You may consider try to create a new project which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you get from the `override` class, in  Portuguese? I've created a new project but the problem still persists.

Comment: Share us your project and detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Here a link to download: https://meocloud.pt/link/3d395f58-85cb-4a43-a537-b363745adb84/IdentityTest.zip/. Just run normally and test by creating a user with wrong data.

Comment: It works with your project. Here is the result [breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovFD8.png) and [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10og.png), what do you mean it does not work?

Comment: Yes, it works. I found the problem. My tests were not including any of the override messages. Thank you very much for your time.